# DataProc Cluster Restart Job Again From CheckPoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have long running job in DataProc Cluster which Query Kafka Topic, I am using GCP Bucket as checkpointing, in case of any failure or job stop  how I ensure that I start the job from same checkpoint i.e read from same data where the failure/stopping occur

Currently in code I have defined this as :

```
.option("checkpointLocation", "gs://checkpoint"+ uuid);
```

So in case of any failure how I can restart a job from same checkpoint ? And also I need to submit a new Job right in case of failure ?